# Como o Facebook escreve colorido no console do navegador?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Estou precisando fazer algo parecido como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível vê-la quando entramos na console do navegador acessando qualquer página do Facebook.

Tentei inserir HTML na função `console.log()`, mas foi em vão. Alguma dica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
console.log('%c Espere!', 'color: red; font-size: 20px;');
```

É no segundo parâmetro que você coloca os estilos que quiser.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue este recurso com a sintaxe abaixo, onde `%c` ativa os estilos CSS à mensagem:

```
console.log('%c Olá!', 'color: red; font-size: 30px;');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Não funciona no IE e Edge (no caso do Facebook, a mensagem de "alerta" apresentada na pergunta sequer é exibida nestes navegadores).

Comment: Mas no IE e no Edge por acaso o Facebook imprime colorido?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado No IE e Edge não imprime nada. A mensagem não aparece.

Comment: Esse detalhe de "nem aparecer no IE nem no Edge" deixaria sua resposta ainda melhor =]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Boa ideia. Obg!

Comment: fico feliz em ajudar =D

Comment: Atualização, no Edge Chromium funciona perfeitamente..